# Android App: How can I print out a String with java code?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, output

I am very new to Android programming!

I want to do something really simple:

```
if(i < 1) 
    System.out.println("Ja");
 else
    System.out.println("Nein");
```

My first idea how to achieve this was to have a TextView in xml with a String resource:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/mytextview"
android:text="@string/Entscheidung"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and then acess that resource via Java code:

```
R.string.Entscheidung = "Ja";
```

but it doesnt work: Error:(13, 17) error: cannot assign a value to final variable Entscheidung

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you !

Comment: `myTextView.setText(i < 1 ? "Ja" : "Nein");`

Comment: "it doesnt work" -- we cannot help you with that if you do not provide a [mcve], showing what you tried and explaining in detail what went wrong.

Comment: Take into account that `R` is created at compile time and it only contains constants, you cannot modify those values from your code.

Comment: i prefer  to take an android tutorial

Comment: Why did I get downvotes for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd just like to clarify the concept of String Resources and how they are used. For constant String values ("Ja" and "Nein" in your case), you can define these values in a file called `strings.xml`, located within the `res/values` folder. As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="antwort_ja">Ja</string>
    <string name="antwort_nein">Nein</string>
</resources>
```

These values are finalized at compile time so can be used as constants throughout your app. In the case of XML layout files, yes you can refer to these String resources using the `@string/` prefix. However, in your Java code you can only refer to these values using the `getString()` method using the `R.string` prefix. Because these `R.string` values are `final`, they cannot be changed at runtime, thus the error you're getting. In your case your code would be:

```
// I'm assuming you have this declared in onCreate()
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview); 

if (i < 1) {
    myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.antwort_ja));
} else {
    myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.antwort_nein));
}
```

This also makes the assumption that you're calling this from your Activity. If not, you may need to call it from an instance of `Context` e.g. `context.getString(R.string.antwort_ja);`

Comment: This works! And thank you for your explanation about String resources! :D

Answer (score 0):

`strings.xml` File:

```
<string name="firststring">Hello World</string>
<string name="secondtring">Welcome</string>
```

Activity or Fragment:

```
textView.setText(i < 1 ? getResources().getString(R.string.firststring) : getResources().getString(R.string.secondtring));
```

Comment: okay but I dont want to "get" the value, I want to "set" the value.. how can I do that?

Comment: or else you can do it this way: if(i<1)
        {
            textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.firststring));
        }else {
            textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.secondtring)); 
        }

Comment: You are already getting the value from res folder, anyhow you are not setting it

Answer (score 0):

First declare your TextView Variable

```
private TextView mTextView;
```

in onCreate

```
mTextView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
```

after that you can work with it

```
if(i < 1) 
    System.out.println("Ja");
 else
    System.out.println("Nein");
```

Can be done with your TextView as below

```
if(i < 1) 
   mTextView.setText(getString(R.String.myJaText);
 else
    mTextView.setText(getString(R.String.myNeinText);
```

In Strings.xml you can write the text you are going to use in your textfield.

You can find Strings.xml into `Res - Values`:

```
<string name="myJaText">Ja</string>
<string name="myNeinText">Nein</string>
```